# How to return indefinetely to previous Step when condition of a following Step is reached Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, jobs

Hello Spring Batch community! I have an input flat file with a header and a body. header is 1 line (naturally..) and 5 parameters. Body can reach up to 1 million records with 12 parameters each.

Input File:

```
01.01.2017|SUBDCOBR|12:21:23|01/12/2016|31/12/2016
01.01.2017|12345678231234|0002342434|BORGIA RUBEN|27-32548987-9|FA|A|2062-
00010443/444/445|142,12|30/08/2017|142,01
01.01.2017|12345673201234|2342434|ALVAREZ ESTHER|27-32533987-9|FA|A|2062-
00010443/444/445|142,12|30/08/2017|142,02
01.01.2017|12345673201234|0002342434|LOPEZ LUCRECIA|27-32553387-9|FA|A|2062-
00010443/444/445|142,12|30/08/2017|142,12
01.01.2017|12345672301234|0002342434|SILVA JESUS|27-32558657-9|NC|A|2062-
00010443|142,12|30/08/2017|142,12
.
.   
.
```

I need to write this into a .txt file with certain format, and in this specific structure:

```
HEADER (8 customed lines, using data from HEADER input)
TITLE OF COLUMNS (1 line)
DETAILS (17 records from the body)
line break
SAME HEADER
SAME TITLE OF COLUMNS
DETAILS (next 17 records from the body)
line break
...
...  
...
REPEAT until end of file
```

What I did was... create a stepHeader and a stepBody . Each of them with their own reader, processor (business formatter) and writer.

The job will have only this 2 simple steps.

```
@Bean
public Job job() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(new JobListener())
                .start(stepHeader())
                .next(stepBody())
                .on("BACK TO STEPHEADER").to(stepHeader())
                .on("END").end().build()
                .build();
}
```

The header i read is configured with MaxItemCount=1,  and mapped it to CabeceraFacturacion:

```
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<CabeceraFacturacion> readerCabecera() throws Exception{

    FlatFileItemReader<CabeceraFacturacion> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

    reader.setLinesToSkip(0);
    reader.setMaxItemCount(1);
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/inputFiles/input.txt"));

    DefaultLineMapper<CabeceraFacturacion> cabeceraLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

    DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer("|"); // en el default, la coma es el separador
    tokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"printDate", "reportIdentifier", "tituloReporte", "fechaDesde", "fechaHasta"});

    cabeceraLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
    cabeceraLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new CabeceraFieldSetMapper());
    cabeceraLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();

    reader.setLineMapper(cabeceraLineMapper);

    return reader;
}
```

The body i read it this way, skipping first line, and mapped it to DetalleFacturacion:

```
@Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<DetalleFacturacion> readerDetalleFacturacion(){

    FlatFileItemReader<DetalleFacturacion> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    //reader.setMaxItemCount(17);
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("/inputFiles/input.txt"));

    DefaultLineMapper<DetalleFacturacion> detalleLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

    DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizerDet = new DelimitedLineTokenizer("|"); // en el default, la coma es el separador
    tokenizerDet.setNames(new String[] {"fechaEmision", "tipoDocumento", "letra", "nroComprobante",  
                                "nroCliente", "razonSocial", "cuit", "montoNetoGP", "montoNetoG3",
                                "montoExento", "impuestos", "montoTotal"});



    detalleLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizerDet);
    detalleLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new DetalleFieldSetMapper());
    detalleLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();
    reader.setLineMapper(detalleLineMapper);


    return reader;
}
```

My Steps:

```
@Bean
public Step stepHeader() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepHeader")
            .<CabeceraFacturacion, CabeceraFacturacion> chunk(17)
            .faultTolerant()
            .listener(new ChunkListener())
            .reader(readerCabecera())
            .writer(writerCabeceraFact())
            .allowStartIfComplete(true)
            .build();
}


@Bean
public Step stepBody() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepBody")
            .<DetalleFacturacion, DetalleFacturacion> chunk(17)
            .chunk(17)
            .faultTolerant()
            .listener(new ChunkListener())
            .reader(readerDetalleFacturacion())
            .writer(writerDetalleFact())
            .listener(new StepExecutionListener() {

                @Override
                public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
                    if(stepExecution.getWriteCount()==17) {

                        return new ExitStatus("BACK TO STEPHEADER");                    
                    };

//                      if(stepExecution.getReadCount()<17) {
//                          return new ExitStatus("END");                   

//                      }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {


                }


            })
            .allowStartIfComplete(true)
            .build();
}
```

1) I don't know how to achieve going back to the StepHeader indefinetely until the file ends. There i tried usind the stepExecution.getWriteCount(17).. but i'm not sure this is the way.

2) i don´t know how to read 17 different records every time it loops ( i managed to make it loop but it would write the same first 17 records over and over again until i manually stopped the job. I now know that loops are not recommended in Spring Batch processes.

3) if anyone has any idea on another way to achieve my goal, it will be most welcome.

4) Is there a way to make a decider that's "hearing" all the time, and sends the order to print header or body if certain condition is satisfied?

Up until now, the max i achieved is to read & write only one time the header... and in the next step read & write 17 lines of the body.

Thank you everyone!
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if i understood your question correctly, But this what you want to achive

Step 1 : Read header from file

Step 2 : Read file ,process data and write to some file Until some condition A

Step 3 : On Condition A Go to Step 1

There can be multiple options to configure this. the one i can think is by adding additional step for flow decision .. below is sample configuration.

**Note** I have not tested this, you might have to do some modifications

```
@Bean
    public Job conditionalJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, Step conditionalStep1, Step conditionalStep2, Step conditionalStep3, Step conditionalStep4, Step conditionalStep5) throws Exception {
        return jobs.get("conditionalJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(flowDesider).on("HEADER").to(step1).next("flowDesider")
                .from(flowDesider).on("BODAY").to(step2).next("flowDesider")
                .from(flowDesider).on("*").stop()
                .end()
                .build();
    }



public class flowDesider implements Tasklet{

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution,
        ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    logger.info("flowDesider");

    //put your flow logic header 
            //you can use step excequation to pass infomrtion from one step to onother      
    if(codition1)
        return status as HEADER
    if (condition2)
        return status as Body
    if condition3
        return status as complited 


}
```

Comment: Thank you Niraj. I'm trying this solution and then i tell you if it worked. By the way, do you know how can i do to print every 17 lines the header again?